# Being stuck at the same page while using post method in a form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have created a simple  post scheme, that would suppose to send input value to a function which has $request variable in a controller named about

When I run, I type "1234" into input box and click the button, It appears

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/about?_token=okqx4sLozgeA3W21nmCnKg5F7oqPqzm6OGpb8nSe&test=1234
```

in the browser address line, not doing anything about the function in controller, and seems to stay at the same page where the form is.

Does anyone have an idea about what the solution could be?

blade:

```
<form action="{{route('admin.about-post')}}" method="post">
    @csrf

     <input type="text" name="test">
            
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

</form>
```

route:

```
Route::post('about-post', 'App\Http\Controllers\back\about@editPost')->name('admin.about-post');
```

controller:

```
class about extends Controller
{

public function editPost(Request $request){


        dd($request); // To test, I should get some results here.


        return redirect()->route('admin.about');


    }

}
```

Comment: Delete compiled views `php artisan view:clear` then delete the compiled route `php artisan route:clear` then try again

Comment: @EsTeAa did both. same results. no action on dd($request);

Comment: `class about extends Controller` you cannot name class with small letter, use `class About extends Controller' and in Route::post('about-post', 'App\Http\Controllers\back\About@editPost')->name('admin.about-post');`

Comment: dont forget to `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: thanks for all. my form was inside another form.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all comments. It has been found that my form was inside another form.
problem solved.